# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ipaddress' (110)

Tags: php, html, mysql, iis-7, windows-server-2008

So I have a PHP file hosted on Namecheap server.

```
$db=mysql_connect  ("ipaddress", "user",  "pass") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
```

and it gives this error:

I cannot connect to the database because: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ipaddress' (110)

I CAN connect to this DB using mysql workbench outside of the network just fine.

Comment: ... you're not connecting to `ipaddress` .. are you? Also, `mysql_` functions have been deprecated. Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: try connecting to 127.0.0.1 ? assuming server and DB on same box?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't clearly say this. But the Namecheap site and MYSQL DB are not on the same network.

Comment: Yes, locally on the same machine 127.0.0.1 I can connect to the DB just fine.

Comment: I am trying to connect to the DB REMOTELY which works fine with MySQL Workbench. but not through the php code. Could Namecheap be blocking incoming port 3306?

Comment: is mysql server at namecheap?  or is mysql server somewhere else?  where is the php code running?  Are both IPS internet accessible?  and yes it is entirely possible that name cheap is blocking access to mysql from $World.  is fairly common thing to do  If you have shell access at namecheap you can use ssh forwarding to get past the firewall.

Answer (score 8):

I have experienced this issue. What I did was use the internet address instead of your public IP/DNS.

Since, I'm using Linux I do `ifconfig` and you will see `inet addr: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and use that IP as your host instead of the public IP/DNS.  On Windows, Simply use your local IP address.

That's it!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using MySQL for your database solution (which seems odd due to the usage of IIS on a Windows Server operating system)

Try running (As Root):

> GRANT ALL ON Database.* TO Username@'IPAddress' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

*Where the second is the permissions that you are granting on, this is a place holder for* **all**

This will allow a connection from the IP you specify

also A problem is with connecting to your MySQL engine from inside your network, you will naturally connect from an internal IPV4 Address (192.168.0.x for example) this does not require portforwarding. BUT if you are using:

`mysql_connect('WANIP', 'User', 'password');`  you will have to forward port `3306` to your server. http://www.portforward.com  for assistance.

**Edit:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

The manual for this subject, this may provide some assistance

---

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server check this link out:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: Yes I have done this:

    GRANT ALL ON *.* TO Username@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

I can try your command later today. I will also check out those other links. I just don't understand why i CAN connect using workbench and not from an offsite server(namecheap) through php.

Comment: @AlMcKenzie Are you using an internal IPV4 Address? or a WANIP?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue when installing opencart on my server. When i was using Windows server it requires IP address of website/domain. Now when shifted to linux hosting, linux hosting accpted as **localhost** And done. I could install opencart