# Error: Can't connect to MySQL Server (110)

Tags: mysql, debian, raspbian

I have a home-hosted MySQL Server which for some reason is giving me this:

```
Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '9x.x.xxx.xx4' (111)
```

I've portforwarded 3306, and when looking for solutions, for example, putting a hashtag before "bind-address", it would not connect me at all. Another example is changing the "bind-address" value to my public IP, but that gave me the same error. I can connect on phpMyAdmin, but not on an external IP or a php file.

Is there anything else I can try?

**EDIT:** I'm now getting this:

```
Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '9x.x.xxx.xx4' (110)
```

Is this something different, or the same?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576521/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-ipaddress-110) helps?

Comment: No, I'm hosting the server/webpage that needs to connect to the MySQL on a different VPS, so I can't do that.

Comment: Anything in the MySQL logs? Can you use something like Telnet to try to connect to the port to see if you get any kind of response? Are you sure your hosting provider doesn't block port 3306? — most do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** I really frown at my younger-self.

What would've been ideal is to actually put `bind-address: 0.0.0.0`, to have the MySQL server listen on all interfaces. But, I was 13 or 14, so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

Okay, I figured it out. In the `my.cnf` file it had this line:

> bind-address: 127.0.0.1

I typed `ifconfig` into the Linux command prompt which gave me my local IP details. All I had to do is change it to that IP. Example:

> bind-address: 192.168.0.X

Thank you to everyone to tried to help me out!

Comment: Kudos for revisiting and updating your answer after almost 5 years :)