# Unable to connect to database error (110)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to move a website and connect to a remote database, but I get the following error:

Unable to connect to the database: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'servername' (110)

With servername being my server I edited (in the connection file the real hostname is written).

I tried adding the IP of the new domain in my cpanel under 'Remote MySQL' but I still get the error.

What could be causing this?

I don't have access to the php.ini files or anything so I can't change anything directly on the server.

Not a duplicate because the supposed duplicate doesn't provide an answer, and I am trying to connect to a remote database, not on the same server as the domain.

My connection file:

```
<?
class Connection {
    // Configure Database Vars
    private $host     = 'servername';
    private $username = 'username';
    private $password = 'password';
    private $db_name  = 'dbname';
    public $db;

    function __construct() {
        // Create connection
        $db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);

        // Check connection
        if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
            die('Unable to connect to the database: '.$db->connect_error);
        }

        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $db = $this->db;
        $this->db->query('SET NAMES utf8');
        if (!$result = $this->db->query($query)) {
            die('There was an error running the query ['.$db->error.']');
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    public function multi_query($query) {
        $db = $this->db;
        if (!$result = $this->db->multi_query($query)) {
            die('There was an error running the multi query ['.$db->error.']');
        } else {
            return $result;
        }

    }

    public function real_escape_string($value) {
        return $this->db->real_escape_string($value);
    }

    public function inserted_id() {
        return $this->db->insert_id;
    }
}

//include 'artikeldb.php';

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ipaddress' (110)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576521/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-ipaddress-110)

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?. that would help

Comment: @Eduardo Added my connection file

Comment: Does your db server accept connections from an external location?

Comment: @DamienPirsy I got a page in my cpanel 'remote mysql' where I can add ip adresses or url's from which a remote connection can be made to the server. I added the url and the ip of the domain but both still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @twan maybe it needs to connect to a different port that default one?, have you ask your provider?

Comment: Please try to enable wild card allow for remote connection on database server